# Google Maps JS API, Hide Map Marker Where 'place_id' Equals

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a Google Map object available on my `window` object like so:

```
var map = window.site.map.el;
```

That `Map` also also has a bunch of markers placed on it, I'd like to hide a `Marker` on that `Map` where the marker's `place_id` property is equal to `"123"` for example.

However I don't see a function I can call on the `Map` class that will return me  an array of all markers placed on the map that I can then loop through and hide depending on the marker's `place_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google maps does not provide a way to get all Markers, you need to do it yourself

while adding marker to the map keep it in array

```
var myMarkers = [];
....
for(...) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({...});
    myMarkers.push(marker);
}
```

Than you can hide any marker, just by setting map to null

```
myMarker[i].setMap(null);
```

Or bring it back

```
myMarker[i].setMap(map);
```